# Unable to load pickle file in streamlit

Tags: python, pickle, streamlit

I have some code to deploy model in streamlit. I just upload all file to github and share it in streamlit app.
Here is some code

```
if str(course) == 'Multi-layer Perceptron':
    file = open("MLP.pkl",'rb')
if str(course) == 'Logistic classifier':
    file = open("log_classifier.pkl",'rb')
if str(course) == 'K-neighbour':
    file = open("Kneighbor_classifier.pkl",'rb')
f str(course) == 'Naivebayes':
    file = open("naivebayes_classifier.pkl",'rb')

model = pickle.load(f)
```

It runs perfect in local. But in streamlit it has some bug

```
ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs.
Traceback:
File "/home/appuser/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/streamlit/script_runner.py", line 354, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/app/nm-khdl/streamlit_app.py", line 45, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(file)
```

It's the first time that I work on streamlit. So, thank you for reading! Have a nice day!

Comment: On `Full error details have been recorded in the logs.` Could you show the logs?

Comment: Yes, I see it. But it doesn't make sense :(

Comment: You are missing a module in `ModuleNotFoundError:`

Comment: Can you post the logs? It will help pinpoint the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. As I saved my model built it in scikit-learn, the pickle file depends on scikit-learn for its structure.

Additionally, I didn't import sckilearn in the python file for the web app streamlit. Therefore, using `pipreqs ./` to generate pip `requirements.txt` file based on imports of this project did not include sklearn.

Thus, I had to include manually it inside of `requirements.txt`: `scikit-learn==0.24.2`

```
numpy==1.22.0
pandas==1.3.4
plotly==5.5.0
streamlit==1.3.0
scikit-learn==0.24.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug and it's quite easy to fix.

Simply create a new txt file. Inside, type

```
scikit-learn
```

Save it as *requirements.txt* in the same directory as your *script_runner.py* file.

Voila, that should do it.